# Make a beautiful binary string

Tags: python, strings, programming-challenge

This is the "[Beautiful Binary String](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/beautiful-binary-string/problem)" problem at HackerRank:

> Alice has a binary string. She thinks a binary string is beautiful if and only if it doesn't contain the substring 010.
>
> In one step, Alice can change a 0 to a 1 or vice versa. Count and print the minimum number of steps needed to make Alice see the string as beautiful.
>
> For example, if Alice's string is 010 she can change any one element and have a beautiful string.

This is my Python code:

```
def beautifulBinaryString(b):
    temp = list(b)
    count,i = 0,0
    if len(b) == 3 and b == "010": count += 1
    elif len(b) == 3 and b != "010": count = count
    else:
        while (i+3 <= len(temp)):
            if temp[i:i+3] == ['0','1','0']: 
                count += 1
                del temp[i:i+3]
            else: i += 1
    return count
```

It seems to me as having too many conditionals (though readable, I guess). Is there a more concise way to accomplish this?

Some test cases:

```
0101010 
01100

2
0
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Style

- [Read the PEP8 style guide!](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?)

  1. Functions and variables should be `snake_case`
  2. Conditions should be on the next line `if a: ...` is bad style
  3. Conditions don't need parenthesis `while (a)` is the same as `while a:`
  4. Avoid `temp` variables

## Algorithm

- Your first 2 guard clauses seem very unnecessary

  When I remove them, the code still works.
- Consider writing docstring/tests or both with the [doctest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html) module

## Alternative Code

You could use `re.findall(substring, string)` for counting the occurrence,

OR `string.count(substring)` making this practically a one-line

```
import doctest

def beautiful_binary_string(b):
    """
    Returns the steps to make a binary string beautiful

    >>> beautiful_binary_string("0101010")
    2

    >>> beautiful_binary_string("01100")
    0

    >>> beautiful_binary_string("0100101010100010110100100110110100011100111110101001011001110111110000101011011111011001111100011101")
    10
    """
    return b.count("010")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: @Tyberius: It seems to work fine because `count` doesn't count overlapping substrings. `'aaa'.count('aa')` is just `1`

Comment: Now, that's some anticlimactic solution :D.

Comment: @EricDuminil Yes somehow this feels more like a *hack* then an actual solution :)

Comment: Indeed, as you answer the question without doing the steps; A non-constructive solution is fine, but 1. you didn't show that doing a step to fix one occurrence doesn't create another one, 2. you didn't show that two overlapping occurrences can be fixed using a single step.

Comment: @Ludisposed Oh I overlooked that, guess I just assumed it had to be more complicated haha. Very clever solution +1. I'll clear my comments since maaartinus's suggestion addresses it

Comment: @maaartinus, in fairness, the correctness of this version is equivalent to the correctness of the code in the question. If OP believes their code to work, they should have no problems trusting this code.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Indeed, it is equivalent... which doesn't imply, it's correct. Anyway, I've upvoted this answer since as CR, it's surely good, I just wanted to point to the potential problems.

Answer (score 10):

> Is there a more concise way to accomplish this?

Certainly.

For a start, the special cases are unnecessary. (They make me think that the code has been refactored from a recursive version).

Secondly, the expensive `del temp[i:i+3]` could be replaced with `i += 3`, and since the processing is no longer destructive `temp` is unnecessary. This simplifies the code to

```
def beautifulBinaryString(b):
    count, i = 0, 0
    while (i+3 <= len(b)):
        if b[i:i+3] == "010":
            count, i = count+1, i+3
        else: i += 1
    return count
```

Comment: I have some very strong reservations about performing two assignments on a single line unnecessarily (and lack of PEP8 compliance). Apart from that, very nice answer.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, OP explicitly prioritised concision, and I don't think that a multiple assignment crosses the line into golfing. But I take your point that it's not uncontroversial.